# My website hosted in the local iis can't load images, js and other files

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am totally new to IIS and this is my first attempt to host one of my websites on my own machine's IIS server.
I installed IIS using `Add windows features on or off` feature and used `aspnet_regiis -i` to install asp on it.

Then I copied my website's content to `wwwroot` directory and I have a partially working website, because some fonts, images, js files and a webm file can't be loaded into the page and when I go to these files by url I get this error message:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME
>   map.

I should mention that I checked `static content` under `common http features` in `Add windows features on or off` but still I have the same problem

Thanks in advance for your help

**UPDATE:**
I used to have a host and domain and this website worked perfectly there, So it Not a website problem

**UPDATE2**
some pictures load ok and some don't.some fonts are ok and some don't.chrome's developer console states an 404 error message for missing files and scripts and when I go to them via url,I get the error message above(which indeed is a 404 error message)

**UPDATE3**
I added woff and webm formats to MIME types so now these types of files work.But still some javascript files won't work since they are using json I json format and json is not added yet to the list of MIME types

What can I do so that ALL TYPES OF FILES are allowed?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET 5?

Comment: No,i am using asp.net 4

Comment: What's the configured root of your website? What folder are the static files located at? What URL are you using?

Comment: The root of my website is a Default.aspx page and some folders that host other aspx pages or my image, js files

Comment: What do you mean the configures root of the website?

Comment: In IIS, when you define a website, you tell it what directory the files come from. That's the root of the site. What did you define as the root?

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, but i just copied my website's folders and files into the wwwroot directory.should i have specified anything else? And how?

Comment: It depends. Like I've said, you need to look in IIS and make sure that the folder is configure as the root directory of a site.

Comment: how can I make sure that it is my root directory?

Comment: Open up IIS. Look at the basic settings for the site. See what directory it is.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your web.config like

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    ...
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    ...
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```